# Excel with CSV table

Tags: excel, csv

We got a measuring device thats connected to a CSV file. Whenever we measure a product the CSV get's updated.

This CSV file is then connected to a excel file to make it user friendly and to add comments. So the CSV file is connected and displayed in a table. We added another column to this table to put a comment.

The problem is when we the csv file updates (new row) the comment of the last row goes down to the new row.

Example: The digits come from the CSV file, and the ok is added manually.

[image]

When we refresh the workbook so the new row gets added we get the following result:

[image]

The ok from row 2 goes down to new row.

It should be like this:

[image]

Is there a way to save/stuck the manually added value to a row?

Comment: (Interesting, what if there is a fourth column for the last line with "The End".)

Comment: There is a 4th and 5th column also with ok/nok. But they also do the same thing.

Comment: Maybe the prior imports did not end with a newline; try with two imports of CSV with an empty line at the end = last data line ending in CR-LF.